# Ionic native geofence onnotificationclicked method is executing very late?

Tags: cordova, ionic2, cordova-plugins, geofencing, ionic-native

I am storing somethings in nativestorage like some location details based on that when ever user opens the app  I am showing some offers to him this is working fine but when user taps the geofence notification I want to update the nativestorage before app loads the previous location offers.Right now onnotification click is taking some time execute because of that previous offers are loading.can anyone give me suggestion?

Comment: So if user click on notification, rewrite storage?

Comment: That is the thing what I am doing now the only thing is this method executes lately compare to page constructor method because of that it's loading previous offers.